# Ionic plugin to mount remote folders

Tags: ionic-framework, remote-access, mount

is possible in Ionic to mount, in app, a remote folder?

Or, if not, is there a workaround to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to say " to mount"  a remote folder?

Comment: I mean mount in the Unix meaning of the term. Mount the folder, list files it, etc.